# UL menu display in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a classic UL multilevel menu that works flawlessly in Firefox.

The LI are `float: left`, and the A inside is `width: 100%` and `display: block` but as you can see from the screenshots below the submenu items (Hello, World and Foobar) display inline.

The weird thing is that this affects the menu even when using canned solutions such as Suckerfish.

What do you suggest i look into to solve the problem?

[image: Menu Item is Open]

[image: Menu Item is Closed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an error in the CSS file that prevented IE from parsing it correctly! Always validate your CSS!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to do a `clear:left;` on the LIs? It would help seeing the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that wasn't the problem. Problem was some CSS error. Lessons learned: always validate your CSS, especially if it gets very long like in these corporate projects. Mine is almost 1000 lines now!!!